# Ng dirty not showing after save button clicked

Tags: angularjs

My application so far is working great. It is not a form (no form tagged used) but it is a series of input boxes that a user must enter. Each input box that a user fills, I am adding an orange border on that input field. I am doing that through:

app.css:

```
#modifyTop .ng-dirty{
  border: 2px orange;
}
```

index.html:
...

```
<body id="modifyTop" name="modifyTop" ng-controller="ModifyPageCtrl">

<button ng-click=save()>Save</button>
```

....

Inside this index.html is a save button. Once I hit the save button, the border field goes away. I am doing this through (I used jQuery inside an Angular controller, not sure if thats acceptable):

ModifyPageCtrl.js:
....

```
function save(){
 ....
  $('#modifyTop .ng-dirty').removeClass('ng-dirty')
...
}
```

So the problem is the following. After hitting save, if say the user wants to change again a particular input field, then it does not make that orange border show up. Only the fields that were previously untouched/not modified have the border appear. I have to reload the page, to make the border appear again in those particular input fields. Can someone please provide examples on how I can make this work? I understand I have given very small snippets of my code thats because my work doesn't allow me to paste company code but I will try to provide more details if people are unable to help with the provided information. Also, would like to mention that my app has no errors- this is a enhancement fix that i am working on.
Thank you

Comment: Just a question, why not use a form tag?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $setPristine():

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

From the docs:

> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state
>   to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class.
>   Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
>
> This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this
>   form.

Comment: I have tried using $pristine but it didnt work and thats because I didnt use the form tag. The reason why I didnt use the form tag is because I am required to use an internal front end library which essentially creates tables and forms etc without those standard tags, its wierd